# Hardware Buttons Hacked :(

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

When I rebooted my phone today some popup appears which `asked for two keys one for navigating screen controls and other select`. I was not able to understand initial objective of this popup and pressed volume up and volume down keys.

After this volume-up key start choosing screen controls like buttons, labels, images with a blue rectangle around. Very same as TAB key behaviour on desktop application and volume down key started behaving as enter key. **Volume increase and decrese won't occur with these keys now**.

My issue is how to trobuleshoot and bring back these keys to normal functioning. I've installed no application for hardware key mapping and *don't want to install a key remapping application without finding this* **hacking** *application*.

Using one plus three with resurrection marshmallow rom.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a hacking at all, it sounds like you turned on Accessibility settings in the Settings application.

Comment: Under accessibility, i've found something called **switch access** disabling that restored phone.  Thanks **RMarkwald** - you're awsome Sir.

Comment: @RMarkwald could you please make that an answer (with some more details and steps to perform to undo it), and Sachin please then "accept" that answer (by ticking the check-mark next to it) – so others can see the issue has been solved? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @Izzy Done as requested.

Comment: Thanks, @RMarkwald – now it's Sachin's turn :) And then, please go for comment-cleanup – and let me know when to remove mine :)

Answer (score 3):

Switch Access may be enabled.  To check/disable this:

Open Settings, click on Accessibility (depending on manufacturer, could be Accessibility Settings), scroll to find Switch Access and turn it Off it is on.